# Does Win32 Listview support local filter?

Tags: windows, winapi

In order to filter data in a `Win32` control `WC_LISTVIEW`, I used to do this by adjusting the data items in the `WC_LISTIVEW`, removing items , then load filter data items. If the data source was related to database, there would be a DB server query , a local data loading, and refreshing.

Does the control `WC_LISTVIEW` supported filter the loaded data locally? I mean filter data from the loaded data records.

Comment: As you might expect, it does not.

Comment: This kind of thing is what the ListView's [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) is intended for.  Don't store the items in the ListView itself, store them off to the side instead, and then you can filter/sort them however you want.  The ListView is just for display, not storage/management.